# #import is doubling up interface definitions and causing error

Tags: objective-c

I have two classes: `RequisitionGetdetails` and `RequisitionRelease`. Both `#import USAdditions.h` in the .m file

Now in class file: `ReqDetailViewController.m` I `#import RequisitionGetdetails.h` and R`equisitionRelease.h` and when I compile I get duplicate interface definition for all objects defined in USAdditions.h

I only use `#import`. I do not have #include anywhere in my code. I thought #import was supposed to handle duplicate definitions like this.
If I comment out `#import RequisitionRelease.h` the duplicate error goes away which tells me the compiler it pulling in the definitions from `USAdittions.h` twice via the other two classes but not ignoring the dups.

Am I wrong in understanding how #import works? Any ideas how to fix this?
I have seen a few similar posts but none of the solutions applied to me or helped me.

Comment: Check every .h thats coming into the class, make sure there not also importing a class that your .h is also importing.

Answer (score 2):

Are you **certain** you're importing the `.h` file and not the `.m` file?

If you `#import` the `.m` file the compiler pretty much copy-pastes the whole file, leading to redefinitions of methods and classes.

I've had that bite me this way in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Benoit's answer, do your .h files have `@implementation`s in them?  If so, then you're defining (not just declaring) the class in two translation units. The class definition ends up in both .o files and when linked, you get duplicate definitions.

Your header files should only have declarations, never definitions.